# A question about Pearson's correlation coefficient

Tags: statistics, correlation, descriptive-statistics

Let be $\rho$ the Pearson correlation coefficient.

Do we have $\rho(X,Y) = \rho(e^X, e^Y)$ ?

Some help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** no

**Hint:** prove it applying [Jensen inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality)